# Map Reduce Wrong Output / Reducer not working

Tags: java, dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to gather max and min temperature of a particular station and then finding the sum of temperature per different day but i keep getting an error in the mapper and Have tried a lot of other ways such as use stringtokenizer but same thing, i get an error.

Sample Input.

Station Date(YYYYMMDD) element temperature flag1 flat2 othervalue

i only need station, date(key), element and temperature from the input

```
USW00003889,20180101,TMAX,122,7,1700
USW00003889,20180101,TMIN,-67,7,1700
UK000056225,20180101,TOBS,56,7,1700
UK000056225,20180101,PRCP,0,7,1700
UK000056225,20180101,SNOW,0,7
USC00264341,20180101,SNWD,0,7,1700
USC00256837,20180101,PRCP,0,7,800
UK000056225,20180101,SNOW,0,7
UK000056225,20180101,SNWD,0,7,800
USW00003889,20180102,TMAX,12,E
USW00003889,20180102,TMIN,3,E
UK000056225,20180101,PRCP,42,E
SWE00138880,20180101,PRCP,50,E
UK000056225,20180101,PRCP,0,a
USC00256480,20180101,PRCP,0,7,700
USC00256480,20180101,SNOW,0,7
USC00256480,20180101,SNWD,0,7,700
SWE00138880,20180103,TMAX,-228,7,800
SWE00138880,20180103,TMIN,-328,7,800
USC00247342,20180101,PRCP,0,7,800
UK000056225,20180101,SNOW,0,7
SWE00137764,20180101,PRCP,63,E
UK000056225,20180101,SNWD,0,E
USW00003889,20180104,TMAX,-43,W
USW00003889,20180104,TMIN,-177,W
```

```
            public static class MaxMinMapper
                 extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

               private Text newDate = new Text(); 

               public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws 
                    IOException, 
                     InterruptedException {


                String stationID = "USW00003889";
                String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
                String station = "";
                String date = "";
                String element = "";
                int data = 0;

                station = tokens[0];
                date = tokens[1];
                element = tokens[2];
                data = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);


                if (stationID.equals(station) && ( element.equals("TMAX") || 
                       element.equals("TMIN")) ) {

                    newDate.set(date);
                    context.write(newDate, new IntWritable(data));

                     }

                 }


              }
```

```
        public static class MaxMinReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

             private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
            public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                int sumResult = 0;
                int val1 = 0;
                int val2 = 0;

                while (values.iterator().hasNext()) {

                        val1 = values.iterator().next().get();
                        val2 = values.iterator().next().get();
                        sumResult = val1 + val2;

                    }

                    result.set(sumResult);


                context.write(key, result);

                }
            }

        }
```

Please help me out, thanks.

UPDATE: Verified each row with condition and changed data variable to String (change back to Integer -> IntWritable at later stage).

```
            if (tokens.length <= 5) {
                station = tokens[0];
                date = tokens[1];
                element = tokens[2];
                data = tokens[3];
                otherValue = tokens[4];
            }else{
                station = tokens[0];
                date = tokens[1];
                element = tokens[2];
                data = tokens[3];
                otherValue = tokens[4];
                otherValue2 = tokens[5];
            }
```

Update2: Ok i'm getting output written to file now but its the wrong output. I need it to add the two values that have the same date (key) What am i doing wrong ?

```
OUTPUT:

20180101    -67
20180101    122
20180102    3
20180102    12
20180104    -177
20180104    -43
```

```
Desired Output
20180101    55
20180102    15
20180104    -220
```

This is the error i recieve aswell, even though i get output.

```
    ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.hadoop) Job [8e31c44ccd394017a4a28b3b16471aca] failed with error:
Google Cloud Dataproc Agent reports job failure. If logs are available, they can be found at 'https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/jobs/8e31c44ccd394017a4a28b3b16471aca
?project=driven-airway-257512&region=us-central1' and in 'gs://dataproc-261a376e-7874-4151-b6b7-566c18758206-us-central1/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/f912a2f0-107f-40b6-94
56-b6a72cc8bfc4/jobs/8e31c44ccd394017a4a28b3b16471aca/driveroutput'.
```

```
    19/11/14 12:53:24 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at cluster-1e8f-m/10.128.0.12:8032
19/11/14 12:53:25 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at cluster-1e8f-m/10.128.0.12:10200
19/11/14 12:53:26 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
19/11/14 12:53:26 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
19/11/14 12:53:26 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
19/11/14 12:53:26 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
19/11/14 12:53:26 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1573654432484_0035
19/11/14 12:53:27 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1573654432484_0035
19/11/14 12:53:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://cluster-1e8f-m:8088/proxy/application_1573654432484_0035/
19/11/14 12:53:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1573654432484_0035
19/11/14 12:53:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1573654432484_0035 running in uber mode : false
19/11/14 12:53:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
19/11/14 12:53:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
19/11/14 12:53:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 20%
19/11/14 12:53:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 40%
19/11/14 12:53:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 60%
19/11/14 12:53:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 80%
19/11/14 12:53:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
19/11/14 12:53:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1573654432484_0035 completed successfully
19/11/14 12:53:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 55
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=120
        FILE: Number of bytes written=1247665
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        GS: Number of bytes read=846
        GS: Number of bytes written=76
        GS: Number of read operations=0
        GS: Number of large read operations=0
        GS: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=139
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=1
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=1
        Launched reduce tasks=5
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=17348
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=195920
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4337
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=48980
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4337
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=48980
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=8882176
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=100311040
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=25
        Map output records=6
        Map output bytes=78
        Map output materialized bytes=120
        Input split bytes=139
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=3
        Reduce shuffle bytes=120
        Reduce input records=6
        Reduce output records=6
        Spilled Records=12
        Shuffled Maps =5
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=5
        GC time elapsed (ms)=1409
        CPU time spent (ms)=6350
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=1900220416
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=21124952064
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1492123648
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=846
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=76
Job output is complete
```

Update 3:

I updated the Reducer (after what LowKey said) and its giving me the same  as output as above. It's not doing the addition I want it to do. It's completely ignoring that operation. Why ?

```
    public static class MaxMinReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

             public IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

             public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                int value = 0;
                int sumResult = 0;
                Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = values.iterator();

                while (values.iterator().hasNext()) {

                    value = iterator.next().get();

                        sumResult = sumResult + value;

                }   

                result.set(sumResult);
                context.write(key, result);
            }

        }
```

Update 4: Adding my imports and driver class to work out why my reducer won't run ?

```
package mapreduceprogram;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
```

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "tempmin");
            job.setJarByClass(TempMin.class);
            job.setMapperClass(MaxMinMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(MaxMinReducer.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path (args[2]));
            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        }

    }
```

Anything wrong with it, as to why my reducer class isn't running ?

Comment: i added a condition to verify each row and bad data, but still nothing written to output. What is wrong now ?

(code in post)

Comment: I've updated my post now, please read the update. I also included the errors im recieving.

Comment: I put it in the post, at the bottom.

Comment: I put it underneath the message your talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing wrong ? Well, for one thing, why do you have:

`final int missing = -9999;`

That doesn't make any sense.

Below that, you have some code that apparently is supposed to add two values, but it seems like you are accidentally throwing away items from your list. See where you have:

`if (values.iterator().next().get() != missing)`

well... you never saved the value, so that means you threw it away.

Another problem is that you are adding incorrectly... For some reason you are trying to add two values for every iteration of the loop. You should be adding one, so your loop should look like this:

```
IntWritable value = null;
Iterator iterator = values.iterator();
while (values.iterator().hasNext()) {
  value = iterator.next().get();
  if (value != missing){
    sumResult = sumResult + value;
  }
}
```

The next obvious problem is that you put your output line inside your while loop:

```
while (values.iterator().hasNext()) {
  [...]
  context.write(key, result);
}
```

That means that every time you read an item into your reducer, you write an item out. I think you what are trying to do is read in all the items for a given key, and then write a single reduced value (the sum). In that case, you shouldn't have your output inside the loop. It should be after.

```
while ([...]) {
  [...]
}

result.set(sumResult);
context.write(key, result);
```

Comment: -9999 is just a condition I need to have due to the original dataset.

Please check update, still getting the same output as before.
Syntax wise i cant do, "IntWritable value = null;" so i'm using int instead and converting to intwritable at the later stage. If thats ok ?

Comment: If you intend to ignore the row of your dataset, it is better if you avoid writing it to the context in the first place, rather than giving it a dummy value to remind you to ignore it later.

Comment: Why can't you do ```IntWritable value = null;``` ? There is nothing wrong with that syntax. And no, you can't set an int equal to null because an int is a primative, not an Object, and primitives can't be null.

Comment: I meant if it's okay to use `Int value = 0;` throughout the code instead of `IntWritable value = null` because when I use this it makes this line     `value = iterator.next().get();` return an error in syntax.

Comment: Yes. You are right. ```iterator.next()``` is an ```IntWritable``` , whereas ```iterator.get().next()``` is apparently an ```int``` .

Comment: You can eliminate the line with the null altogether by just putting this inside the loop:  ``` int value = iterator.next().get();```

Comment: Yes, this is what I done but still, same problem, wrong output, its not doing the addition part.

Comment: Is it possible that your reducer is not running at all? Can you add a print statement to prove that your program ran that code?

Comment: If put in some print statements but im struggling to find where I can find the result as im using GCP.

Comment: Since you don't know where to find the output of print statements, can you output some symbolic number instead of the actual values? For example, instead of ```context.write(key, result)``` , can you use ```context.write(key, 666)``` ? If the reducer is being invoked, your output data should contain only rows of ```666``` . Having access to your console output is essential for debugging. I suggest your research where to find it ASAP.

Comment: Yeah i changed, `context.write(key, result)` to `context.write(key, 666)` in the reducer and it didn't print the 666 value per row with key, when I put `context.write(key, 666)`, in the mapper it however did produce the 666 values per row with key. So it seems my reducer is not being invoked at all and im not sure as to why .. hmm ?

Answer (score 0):

Are those columns separated by tabs?
If yes, then don't expect to find a space character in there.

Comment: Even if i change the input file and make the delimiter a comma and change this line to               String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",") ... I Still get errors.

Comment: I changed the sample input to proper csv file separated by commas to help make it easier to find what the problem is

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.hadoop) Job [bff3d49c64594c039dca927319fd284e] failed with error:
Google Cloud Dataproc Agent reports job failure. If logs are available, they can be found at 'https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/jobs/bff3d49c64594c039dca927319fd284e
?project=driven-airway-257512&region=us-central1' and in 'gs://dataproc-261a376e-7874-4151-b6b7-566c18758206-us-central1/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/f912a2f0-107f-40b6-94
56-b6a72cc8bfc4/jobs/bff3d49c64594c039dca927319fd284e/driveroutput'.

Also output files are empty, there's no results... dont know whats wrong.

Comment: Also, did you happen to notice that your data rows have an inconsisent number of columns, apparently with inconsistent data types in the final columns? Are you sure the dataset is good?

Comment: Yes, i've noticed that in dataset and that's how it's suppose to be. I also included what the logs were in the post, updated it.

Comment: Do you mind reading me the package of the Reducer class? Until now I've been able to answer your questions agnostic to this... but at this point we really need to look at the implementation details.

Comment: What you do you mean by the package of the reducer class ?

Comment: At the top of your MinMaxReducer.java there is a line that starts with "import" and ends with "Reducer" .

Comment: `import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;`

Im going to put my imports and driver class in the post, have no clue why my reducer won't run.

Comment: I think the mapper and reducer need to have matching type signatures in order to be linked. Can you change your mapper class to extend this parameter prototype? class MaxMinReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now. If i wanted to work out the difference between the two values with the same key, how would i go about it ?

Comment: You can't do what you're describing. Your current code accumulates a sum of all elements it encounters. It can do this regardless of how many items match a given key. A difference operation is defined only between exactly two numbers. How do you imagine you could compute the difference between 10 items? Between 1 item?

Comment: I only have two values, TMAX and TMIN. Is it not possible to iterate through values and do value(tmax) - value2(tmin). Or how would i go about it to make this possible ?

Comment: Yes. You can define max and min over the set. That is not the same as difference. If you have only 1 item, you can still have min and max. You can also define the difference between min and max which is essentially a range. If you are asking me how to evaluate the man and max of a sequence of numbers, that is pretty basic... but your question has been answered, so please be so kind as to grant me credit for the hours I've spent helping you. If you have another question to ask, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: Yes thank you your help, I appreciate your help, I asked another question about this. Thanks.

Comment: I’ve tried it and I’m getting minus answers, possible for you to check my other question please ? Thanks. Will appreciate your help again.